# Get total row count in views-view-fields.html.twig

Tags: views, theming

How can I get the total rows number in **views-view-fields.html.twig** template file in Drupal 8? In Drupal 7, I can get it by the following code.

```
$view = views_get_current_view();
$view->total_rows;
```

Is there any variable to render the total number of rows in Drupal 8?

Comment: {{ view.total_rows }} is working when pager **NOT** set as  **Display a specified number of items**, set as **mini or full** will print the total row number.

Comment: For some reason, it seems to work only on **FULL**, at least on a 8.4.x site. Not on **mini**

Comment: You should do these things in preprocess functions. Look here for a working snippet on views count: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/get-views-row-count-twig-drupal-8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use simple code `{{ view.total_rows }}` in every file template views. Variable **view** is global.

Comment: I think `{{ view }}` variable is not available in views-view.html.twig.

Comment: Thanks for reply {{ view.total_rows }} print only 0 as value in both views-view-fields.html.twig & views-view.html.twig when there suppose 5 in my case.

Comment: @AshishDeynap you can debug with {{ dump(_context|keys) }}

Comment: @wzh what's your field type?

Comment: Since in views-view-fields.html.twig, It is a group of fields including image, text etc.

Comment: Oddly enough, {{ view.total_rows }} is working when pager **NOT** set as  **Display a specified number of items**, set as **mini or full** will print the total row number, thanks!

Comment: {{ view.total_rows }} does not exclude the access forbidden items

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 8, views-view.html.twig contains few pre defined variables. Among them, there is a `{{ rows }}` variable that contains **"The results of the view query, if any."**

To get total number of row count, use `{{ rows | length }}`. It will print total number of rows count and if you want it in a variable, do as `{% set count = rows | length %}`

Comment: Thank you for quick reply but I think {{ rows }} only available views-view.html.twig level not at views-view-fields.html.twig that is where I want it to show.

Comment: Not used it actually, but found a variable in views-view-fields.html.twig **row: The raw result from the query, with all data it fetched.**

Comment: Yes it is row not rows so {{ rows | length }} doesn't work

Comment: you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/views_record_count module

Comment: This is (no longer?) correct for `views-view.html.twig`, because `rows` always is an array containing only one nested array. However `{% set count = rows.0['#rows'] | length %}` worked for me in v8.4.3

Answer (score 2):

you can use {{ view.result | length }} in views-view-fields.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

If you use an exposed filter and want to show the unfiltered number of total results (like "we are showing you 12 items out of total 345 items"), this gets slightly more complicated. In a `preprocess_views_view` or any other preprocess which gets the view as a variable, run

```php
  // Pass original view row count to template
  $pager = \Drupal::service('pager_manager');
  $pager = $pager_manager->getPager();
  $request_stack = \Drupal::requestStack();
  $request = clone ($request_stack->getCurrentRequest());
  $request->query = new ParameterBag;
  $request_stack->push($request);
  $original_view = $variables['view'];
  $view = Views::getView($original_view->id());
  $view->setDisplay($original_view->current_display);
  $view->preExecute($original_view->args);
  $view->execute();
  $view->postExecute();
  $request_stack->pop();
  $pager_manager->createPager($pager->getTotalItems(), $pager->getLimit());
  $variables['total_rows'] = $view->total_rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

One another way to get the total row counts is by directly querying the database for the results. You can use something like below:

```
$total_results = \Drupal::database()
  ->select('view_name')
  ->countQuery()
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();
```