# Views get total row count in views-view.html.twig

Tags: views

I need to get the total rows count in **views-view.html.twig** file. So that I can loop through it and create the indicators required for my bootstrap carousel view block.

I tried the solution provided in this thread [Drupal 8 Views get total row count in views-view-fields.html.twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223415/drupal-8-views-get-total-row-count-in-views-view-fields-html-twig) but nothing seems to be working.

Can any one please guide me how its possible.

Comment: `So that I can loop through it and create the indicators` why do you need a number (row count) to loop through stuff?

Comment: Try this module https://www.drupal.org/project/views_record_count

Comment: I tried that module but it was not working for me.

Comment: I want total row count because I want to loop through that number to create bullet indicators.

Comment: `create bullet indicators` for Format use HTML List, that will make each row bullets.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved as follows. NB this outlines a simple approach which works. It can be finessed and improved upon by stripping our unnecessary divs, applying classes more elegantly, etc, but this will work:

- Adding a views attachment display and attaching it to your main
  display of the slides (display: after);
- Set this attachment with an ordered list display format with List class = carousel-indicators;
- Add one custom text field (it will not be displayed so it does not really matter what this is);
- Set it to evaluate the same conditions as your main display (eg content filtered by a boolean "display in slider" = TRUE ... or whatever). This way number of bullets definitely = number of slides;
- Copy the core views-view-list.html.twig to your theme and override with your
  display name (see api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.3.x for general suggestions);
- Return the rows as follows:

  `{% for row in rows %}
       {% if loop.first %}
        <li{{ row.attributes }} data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{{ loop.index }}" class="active">{{ row.content }}</li>
       {% else %}
        <li{{ row.attributes }} data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{{ loop.index }}">{{ row.content }}</li>
       {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}`

This gets the active class on the first item and includes the index number, thus matching the requirements at: getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Controls and required wrappers can be set simply in the views-view.html.twig:

```
 {% if rows %}
```

`<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">`

```
 {{ rows }}
```

`<!-- Controls -->`
`
(...etc..)

Slide wrapper and active class can be set in views-view--unformatted.html.twig for the slides themselves:

```
 `<!-- Wrapper for slides -->`
```

`<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">`

`{% for row in rows %}
   {% if loop.first %}
    <div class ="active item">
    {{ row.content }}
    </div>`

`{% else %}
   <div class ="item">
    {{ row.content }}
   </div>`

`{% endif %}
 {% endfor %}`

`</div><!-- end slider wrapper -->`

Working example: http://wri.netuxosandbox.co.uk/en

Comment: Oops! I realised two things:
1. The attachment should be attached BEFORE and not AFTER;
2. Therefore the wrapping div needs to come before the attachment is called - so this worked for me:

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  {% if attachment_before %}
    <div class="attachment attachment-before">

...etc

Comment: I did the same but the attachment is reloading the master block, that is reloading the view-view-page.html.twig. That I have override with the view name.

Comment: Now I attached it to the Master block and attachment content is not appearing. Please guide me.