# taking in account access forbidden items in views total row count

Tags: views

the `{{ view.total_rows }}` inspired by [Get total row count in views-view-fields.html.twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223415/get-total-row-count-in-views-view-fields-html-twig)

is not accurate when some rows are not accessible to the user.

Any idea how can we display the current total row accessible to the user?